# How can I import values from given URL to python?

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

How can I extract the value of the last price of the strike price 12,000.00 from the given URL in python?

https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10006&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17

LTP of 12,000.00 strike price is 25.35.

Answer (score 1):

With bs4 4.7.1 use `:has` and `:contains`. Use `:contains` with `td:nth-of-type` to search the right column, then `:has` to retrieve the parent row and `descendant combinator` and `td:nth-of-type` again, to get the ltp column value for that row.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

r = requests.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10006&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
ltp = soup.select_one('#octable tr:has(td:nth-of-type(12):contains("12000.00")) td:nth-of-type(6)').text.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/option_chain/optionKeys.jsp?symbolCode=-10006&symbol=NIFTY&symbol=NIFTY&instrument=-&date=-&segmentLink=17&symbolCount=2&segmentLink=17')

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"lxml")

data = []
for tr in soup.select('table#octable tr')[2:-1]:
    data.append([td.text.strip() for td in tr.select('td')])

def get_ltp(data, strike_price):
    for d in data:
        if strike_price == d[11]:
            return d[5]

print(get_ltp(data, '12000.00'))
```

Prints:

```
25.35
```

Comment: Thank you @ Andrej Kesely. Can you please explain to me what logic did you apply to get the desired result?

Comment: @AdityaTaide First I selected the main table (`table#octable`), then i striped the headers (first 2 rows) and last row. The function `get_ltp()` just compares the desired `strike_price` in column 11, and if its equal than in table, returns column 5 (ltp)

Comment: next thing I am trying to store the last price values into a list dynamically. I tried using threading.Timer(5, get_ltp(data,'12000.00')).start() but it shows recursion error.